# How to tell when Firefox completes a download?

Tags: firefox, selenium, download, firefox-addon, signals

I'm writing a program that needs to know when Firefox completes a download. I'm not looking for a hack, like looking in the download directory to see if the file size is still changing, because all solutions like that will probably lend themselves to race conditions. I'm looking to receive some kind of programmatic signal from Firefox itself. I believe this would be possible by creating a Firefox Addon, but since I've never written an Addon before, I'm looking to use an existing solution if there is one, before I go re-inventing the wheel.

The program I'm writing is currently using Selenium to run Firefox, so if Selenium has an existing solution to this problem that you know of, that would be cool too.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood you, but I'm not sure why you'd want to launch Firefox just to download a file. Anyway, you can add a [download progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadProgressListener) to the [download manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadManager). There's even an example of [monitoring downloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Monitoring_downloads).